# From spectrogram (Bin magnitudes) back to sound signal, JS

Tags: javascript, signal-processing, fft, spectrogram

As a result of a learning algorithm in JavaScript, I have magnitude data for signals at certain frequency bins, basically **spectrogram data**. What I want to do is to **construct a composite sound signal**.

My main question is: Is this possible ?
Since the magnitude can be the result of an infinite amount of complex numbers, i.e. a circle in the complex plane, it is not clear which one to use. This might not matter, but to build the signal, in my limited understanding, I would need to know the exact complex number so that I know its phase. This might be very wrong, but that's why I'm here! :)

Then, if this is possible, how would I do this? 
I thought about using a reverse FFT but I think I do not have the right input.

Please correct wrong statements. 
Any relevant insights are welcome, I have a lot to learn about this, and I want to. 
Thanks!

Comment: You can generate an approximate version of the time domain signal using an inverse FFT, but you are lacking phase information.

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean that I could generate an approximate version if I had phase information, or that I can anyway, but that it would be more accurate with phase information?

Comment: You can generate an approximate version with frequency domain magnitude information only, in that it will have the correct frequency components at the correct magnitude, but the actual shape of the waveform is highly dependent on phase information, which you lack. So you will have to use some arbitrary phase for each component. You may or may not care about the time domain representation (without knowing what problem you're trying to solve it's hard to say) - for many cases such an approximation *may* be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will test if I have enough accuracy with arbitrary phases. :)

Comment: You might want to try applying a random phase to each bin the frequency domain (rather than e.g. setting all the phases to 0) - this can help to prevent the time domain signal from being too "spiky" (i.e. avoid excessive crest factor).

Comment: Ahh, that would be a kind of resonance effect, I speculate. Thank you for the tip, and your help !

Comment: I tested it out, and the sound signal is very precise to my ears. Listening attentively, I cannot distinguish it from the original, in case anyone interested stumbled on this post. So thanks Paul!

Comment: Yes, that is to be expected - human hearing is not particularly sensitive to *absolute* phase, although we do make good use of *relative* phase, binaurally, for localisation of sound sources.